# SQL injection attack boolean operators

Tags: sql, sql-injection, boolean-expression

In SQL injection attack what is the value of X AND ((1=1) OR (1=0))?

Can you please explain this step by step?
is (1=1) the same as just 1, is (1=0) the same as just 0?

Comment: I edited the subject from "bitwise operators" to "boolean operators." The expression you show is not bitwise, despite the values being compared being 1 and 0. Those are just integers, not bits. It would work the same with other values like `('banana' = 'banana' OR 'banana' = 'orange')`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, (1=1) is the same of 1 or `True`, (1=0) is the same as just 0 or `False`

If you get confused and you are running MySQL, you could also run something like this to get your answers easily:

```
SELECT 1=1, 1=0, (1=1 OR 1=0)
```

So step-by-step it would be:

1. `(1=1) OR (1=0)` equals to `True OR False`.
2. `True or False` equals to `True`
3. So the value of `X AND True` would be equal to `X`

Comment: What you wrote does, in its generality, not apply to all DBMS but MySQL.

Comment: @stickybit Why do you say that? I know it's nonstandard that MySQL treats 1 and true as the same thing, but `1=1` should evaluate to a boolean `true` in all SQL databases (just as `'banana'='banana'` evaluates to boolean `true`).

Comment: @BillKarwin: OK, maybe I should have been more verbose: Try `SELECT 1=1, 1=0, (1=1 OR 1=0)` in SQL Server or Oracle (with a `FROM DUAL` appended) and you won't have much success. In Postgres it'll work in general but won't give you 0s or 1s as it has a genuine Boolean type. Also expressions like `true or false` will get you nowhere in Oracle or SQL Server. (Note: This is about using `true` or `false` as literals as the answer suggests. Of course behind the curtains, comparison expressions, Boolean operations, etc. evaluate *internally* to true or false.)

Comment: @stickybit Thanks, edited my answer giving more details about where to run the test. For the sake of simplicity and not going much away from the actual answer I didn't go much further, but he could try something like `SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` for MSSQSL, which is about the same approach to test the idea.

Answer (score 0):

`1=1` and `1=0` are comparison operators. The evaluation of `1=1` will always be true, so everything from statement X will be returned no matter what. The idea of a SQL injection is that a user can pass an argument into a form input, where the values are used in a SQL call that does not properly check to make sure the input will not cause issues. If a user enters input into, lets say a search query, with the value of `OR 1=1--` (where `--` comments out the rest of the query), the statement that is used on the server side will return data that the user is not supposed to see because the input is a valid SQL command. That is why the comparison is used.

Comment: `X AND (TRUE)` is not always true. It depends if X is false (0) or true (non-zero).